# OpenAPI - How to document parameters that should be of type 'function', like OData's $apply

Tags: odata, openapi

I am trying to document an OData query parameter with OpenAPI.
It looks something like this:

```
$apply=aggregate(Amount with sum as Total)
```

I am not expecting much, but I would like OpenAPI to at least check that the caller is restricted to a function name **aggregate**.

Are there any options here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out how using string patterns:

```json
"schema": {
  "type": "string",
  "pattern": "^aggregate\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]* with (sum|min|max|average)\\)$"
}
```

By using RegEx one could possibly support all of the complexities of OData.

I wish something like that would have been posted here:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-openapi/v1.0/odata-openapi-v1.0.html